# css and js file not accessible on localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am running existing laravel project from VSCode using command

```
php artison serve
```

it run the application but css and js file not reflecting on pages.

When I open the source by right click on page, found  path is coming  like below
http://localhost:8000/**public**/css/

When I remove public from path css is accessible from browser

```
http://localhost:8000/css/
```

I tried command

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

also as some user suggested but same result.

Why larvel generating path with public folder and how i can fix it.

Comment: Show us your Blade file where you generate your links to your CSS file, and check the `APP_URL` value in `.env`.

Comment: I would also recommend switching to Laravel Sail

Comment: First of all, what Laravel version are you using?
Laravel is using public folder to serve files while all other folders and files are out of the public folder, as a way to increase the system security.  
When I run php artisan serve, public path is automatically remove from path in blade generated files. How are you linking your assets? can you put your blade file to see how it is calling CSS and JS?

Comment: @Farid I am using Laravel 8.83

Comment: @ceejayoz  Farid attaching css and ls like below     <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Your calls looks correct, so I think that there must be another issue. I've also tried wih `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` and it works fine for me. The only difference I saw is when using artisan url is `127.0.0.1:8000`, and when using `php -S`url is `localhost:8000`, but in both cases I haven't `public` segment in html source path.

Comment: I will suggest you to use laravel valet for local server in your development machine. Although is a mac application there are forks for windows and linux too, and it is a really lightweight and simple development ambient for laravel and other PHP+MySQL projects.